# Want to Make Itunes only play when I explicitly unpause or start it

Tags: itunes

I occasionally play music using itunes, and I tend to pause the music rather than e.g. quitting from itunes.

This afternoon I received an email with an audio attachment, which I played.

As soon as the playback finished, itunes started playing, quite likely the song I had paused 2 weeks ago.

I don't ever want it to do that again.

Is there any way to control this behaviour other than explicitly quitting from itunes whenever I'm done with it, and making sure I don't select "Open at login" in options?

I'm running OS X version 10.9.4, and I'm *not* a power user.

"About itunes" isn't cooperating with me - it scrolls as I try to record things - so the itunes version I'm running is anyone's guess (whatever IT put on the system). It might be 11.2.1 (1) 64-bit.

[edit: 1 day later, I brought up itunes, and found that the email attachment had become one of the songs itunes was willing to play. Not only that, it had been added to the front of the list of things to play, such that when I unpaused itunes, it started playing the voicemail message(!) - not e.g. the song it had been on when I had most recently paused and then quit itunes. I had never ever told itunes to play that attachment, save it, or add it to my library. *All* I had ever done was doubleclicked on the attachment in Outlook.]

Comment: Did you by chance hit any of the keyboard controls for music playback as the audio attachment was ending? (Like maybe pause, as you state you tend to do?) That's one of only two ways I can think of the situation you describe occurring. The other possibility is if you double-clicked on the attachment in Mail, it may have added itself to iTunes, and then when it was done kept playing music from your iTunes Library.

Comment: I don't have 10.9.x around to test, but I just tried in 10.10.0 playing an MP3 received in an email within Mail and it did not proceed to play anything from iTunes afterwards.

Comment: I don't think I hit any controls. It can be hard to tell - lots of gestures I don't know. But certainly not intentionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This afternoon I received an email with an audio attachment, which I played."

Did you double-click it, or Open, which would open it in iTunes?

Once you've set iTunes going it will then follow its pre-set behaviour, which includes playing the following song.

If you don't want to bother iTunes at all with the audio file, you can simply select it & tap Space Bar, which will make Quick Look play it instead. This won't touch iTunes, won't add it to its data storage, nor will it then play anything else once it's finished.
You can start/pause or change playback location. Space Bar again will close it.

The only thing you can't do is select something else in the same app whilst it's playing, or it will Quick Look that instead.

Comment: I double clicked on the attachment in outlook.